# Android ListView Like PhoneBook

Tags: android, listview, android-gesture

How to make ListView rows behave like in PhoneBook?

I want to send a message when I drag the line to the right (swipe right).

I want to call a person when I drag the line to the left (swipe left).

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/508/81848287.png/]

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/73736840.png/]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Header separated list adapter , where some of the child items will be non clickable headers and others will be clickable sections .
[follow this tutorial](http://androidseverywhere.info/JAAB/?p=6)

Comment: You understand me wrong.
I want to send out messages when I drag the line to the right.
Let the call and when I drag the line to the left.

Comment: ok . implement a gestureListner . overridden  onFling method will track left/right fling . do appropriate action